# How to convert current date time from IST to EST timezone in Android?

Tags: android, date, timezone

How to get the EST timzone date (already convrted and get String) into date format with its Timezone?
I tried with changing timezone and I got the perfect datetime in string format but while I am parsing that String date into date format it gives me local Android system timezone time.
Thanks for any help...in advance.

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
outputFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
String current_date =  outputFormat.format(date);
Date currentdate = outputFormat.parse(current_date);
```

It give's me EST date format in String (current_date).
It give's me IST format date (currentdate)

Comment: You need to use [valid time zone identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  If by EST you mean North American Eastern Time, use `"America/New_York"`.  If by IST you mean India Standard Time, use `"Asia/Kolkata"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually `reversing` the output from the string back to its original timezone, so when you **format** the Date from `IST` to `EST` it will give you the right specified timezone but by the time you `parse` it will revert it back to its current timezone the phone is currently using.

**solution:**

use another instance of `SimpleDateFormat` and use that to `parse` the string to prevent it to be reverted back to its current timezone

**sample:**

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");
outputFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
String current_date =  outputFormat.format(date);

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
Date currentdate = outputFormat2.parse(current_date);
```

Comment: @KDOSHI it will give you IST but the time itself is EST

Comment: You are right but it gives me like this Sat Aug 09 01:44:00 GMT+05:30 2014 If i want to compare the two dates like if(expirydate.compareTo(currentdate)>0) then it will effective or not!

Comment: I think you cant change the toString format of the date, instead you can manipulate the String, so instead of comparing date, you compare string and replace the GMT with EST using `replace` method of String

Comment: String comparison is not valid solution in the case of date comparison.

Comment: @KDOSHI there is no way to change that TimeZone of the Date because it is using `getDefault` which is the default Timezone of your device.

Comment: @KDOSHI I would recommend using JODA time if you really want to compare it with timezones, that is because date in java is `broken`